# Angular 2 - script5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I created a simple project:

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve
```

Chrome and Firefox it's OK, but when I execute in IE 11, it returns this error: SCRIPT5007

[image]
[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this issue can be reproduced in Angular 2.4 and you can fix this by using Angular 2.2.x or 2.3.x.
I have filed an issue for the Angular team, here is the link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14592

=================================================

It seems it is not an issue of angular, but angular cli. Please refer to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4862

As the answer of the angular-cli issue said, the IE11 polyfills are commented out by default, you need to enable the polyfills in src\polyfills.ts.

Comment: The answer by Ali Adravi below should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

It is the issu of CLI not the angular

In newer version of ANGULAR - CLI, src\polyfills.ts are commented out by default.

1. open file `src/polyfills.ts`
2. un-comment these files and done

BROWSER POLYFILLS

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

Here is the list of files:

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: I am getting same issue in `IE` and `Safari` , I uncomment  the relevant lines in `polyfill.js` after this it working on `IE` but  `safari` still showing same error.please suggest how to resolve this in safari.